# Could we use evolutionary computation to have a computer create formulas for number sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, computability

After going through OEIS and noticing many sequences that are very beautiful and have an apparent structure to them I have wondered if a computer would have a better chance of formulating an answer. Using evolutionary computation could you have a computer hone in on formulas that are too complex for us humans to handle? If so, why don't we utilize this technique?

Comment: This has been done as a Kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/integer-sequence-learning

Comment: We don't want formulas, we want a proof that the given formula is correct. And finding proof is very hard, as you can't have bounds on the length of a proof, and you don't even know if a proof exists : This is beyond what a computer can do. (this is linked to Gödel incompletness theorems)
And "evolutionary computation" means nothing serious or useful...